# Not resolved dependency in instantiated gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

Installer:

```cs
class MainInstaller : MonoInstaller<MainInstaller>
{
    [SerializeField]
    private StateController StateController;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInstance( StateController );
    }
}
```

Behaviour with injection:

```cs
class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Inject]
    private StateController StateController;

    void Start()
    {
        UpdateObject( StateController.Current );
    }
}
```

Problem is `StateController` is null at `UpdateObject`.

Should I instantiate gameobject somehow especially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject/issues/57.

`GameObject.Instantiate` does not resolve dependencies. One should use `DiContainer.InstantiatePrefab` or use Factories.